# Get MSXML to report version

Tags: xslt, msxml

I'm in a bit of a weird spot.  Due to events too ridiculous to list here, I'm working with a system that uses an unknown XSL engine.  I'm *fairly* certain it's MSXML.  The problem is that I'm not entirely sure which version (this is important).  The original devs aren't available, and I have very limited access to the back end.  What I **do** have the ability to do is author content (that gets fed through the XSLT sheets) and to edit the XSLT itself.  Given these two abilities, is there any way I can make the parser report its version?  Anything like PHP's [`phpversion()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php)?  Maybe even a standard way to report the XSL engine vender *and* version?

I'd be very willing to write a feature check sheet, if I could just find a list of XSL engines, and features unique to each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process [this XSLT stylesheet](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/processorTest3.xml) with your XSLT processor, it outputs some system properties, including the Microsoft `msxsl:version`.

Comment: Huh, Apache.  The one time I've ever *not* been happy to find a non-Microsoft technology.

Comment: Following namespace should be declared for this to work: `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"`

Answer (score 1):

`<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/>` will tell you if it is Microsoft, but there is no property in XSLT 1.0 to tell you the version, only in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Excelent!  @MartinHonnen eeks by your answer just slightly, though, because of the MSXSL specific tag `msxsl:version`.  You still get a +1, though.